# cloudformation error - Value of property SubnetIds must be of type List of String

Tags: aws-cloudformation

When I run create-stack it fails with the creation of elasticsearch domain with this error - "Value of property SubnetIds must be of type List of String"
Here is the snippet of the CF template...

```
Parameters:
  SubnetIds:
    Type: 'List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>'
    Description: Select a VPC subnet to place the instance. Select Multiple Subnets for multi-AZ deployments

Resources:
  ElasticsearchDomain:
    Type: 'AWS::Elasticsearch::Domain'
    Properties:
      AccessPolicies:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            AWS: '*'
          Action:
          - 'es:ESHttp*'
          Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:es:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:domain/${DomainName}/*'
      DomainName: !Ref 'DomainName'
      EBSOptions:
        EBSEnabled: !Ref EBSEnabled
        VolumeSize: !Ref EBSVolumeSize
        VolumeType: gp2
      ElasticsearchClusterConfig:
        DedicatedMasterCount: !If [HasDedicatedMasterNodes, !Ref DedicatedMasterCount, !Ref 'AWS::NoValue']
        DedicatedMasterEnabled: !If [HasDedicatedMasterNodes, true, false]
        DedicatedMasterType: !If [HasDedicatedMasterNodes, !Ref DedicatedMasterType, !Ref 'AWS::NoValue']
        InstanceCount: !Ref ClusterInstanceCount
        InstanceType: !Ref ClusterInstanceType
        ZoneAwarenessEnabled: !If [HasSingleClusterInstance, false, true]
      ElasticsearchVersion: !Ref ElasticsearchVersion
      EncryptionAtRestOptions: !If [HasKmsKey, {Enabled: true, KmsKeyId: !Ref KMSEncryptionKey}, !Ref 'AWS::NoValue']
      SnapshotOptions:
        AutomatedSnapshotStartHour: 0
      VPCOptions:
        SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref SecurityGroup
        SubnetIds:
        - !Ref SubnetIds
```

Tried it like this as well but doesn't work -

```
        SubnetIds:
        - [!Ref SubnetIds]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use the following code snippet :

```
  VPCOptions:
    SubnetIds: !Ref ESSubnetsID
    SecurityGroupIds: !Ref ESSecurityGroup
```

And update the parameters section with the following :

```
  ESSubnetsID:
    Description: Choose which subnets the Elasticsearch cluster should use
    Type: 'List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>'
    Default: 'subnet-1,subnet-2'
  ESSecurityGroup:
    Description: Select the SecurityGroup to use for the Elasticsearch cluster
    Type: 'List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>'
    Default: 'sg-1,sg-2'
```

Make sure you pass **List** of subnets ids.

Answer (score 1):

Like the error message says, SubnetIds should be a List of strings not a `List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>` as you defined it in your params section. Redefine it properly as `List<String>` and it will work.

```
Parameters:
  SubnetIds:
    Type: 'List<String>'
```

Comment: In general you right,The Subnet ids must be a list of strings . But, you can still use the `List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>` type since it's an array of strings. The benefits are when you create the stack you can select the subnets from a drop-down list and it is helpful in catching invalid values at the start of creating or updating a stack. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html